# Looking to assign percentage contribution among 4 variables in a simple equation

Tags: statistics, applications

I have a seemingly simple problem, that is giving me some trouble in solving. I have a 4 variable equation and want to determine the contribution of each variable in moving the dependent variable from time $t_0$ to time $t_1$.

The equation looks like: $y = a\cdot\frac{b}{c}\cdot d$

I need to assign a percentage of each variable (totaling to 100%) responsible for the change in $Y$.
$$
\begin{align}
t_0 &: -0.4\cdot\frac{205,000}{640}\cdot 0.6 = -76\\
t_1 &: 3.94\cdot\frac{916,000}{320}\cdot 1.85 = 20,864
\end{align}
$$

There is a total delta of $20,940$, and I need to assign a percentage of "responsibility" for this delta among the four variables changing. My approach was to "take away" each of the variable changes individually, then add up the resulting deltas and simply take each delta from each individual X and divide by the sum of the deltas to determine percentage.

As I worked it out, I get $a = 36\%, b = 16\%, c = 22\%,  d = 25\%$

It's a very simple sensitivity analysis, but I really don't have theoretical backup. Is there a better way that I am missing?

Comment: Why not using the derivatives ?

Comment: what are equations of $X_i(t)$? Your answer depends on these.

Comment: Thanks for looking @PA6OTA! This is a real world problem.....  I just have the numbers as given  from data.

Comment: Thanks for looking @ClaudeLeibovici. I'm not sure derivatives get me to percentages, as the magnitude of X2 is so large. Also, all the variables change over the time period, so I'm not sure that a derivative gives me help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just for the sake of documentation.  I found justification for what I did, it's called swing weighting, and it is part of the multi attribute utility theory (MAUT).

Thanks!